# how can I parse ajax response in jquery?

Tags: ajax, jquery

I want to know how can we parse the response from the ajax in jquery script.

EDITED :

Here is my jquery : jquery_test.jsp

```
 <h1>Hello World!</h1>

    <select id="body_id" name="current_session" >
            <option value="Winter">Winter</option>
            <option value="Monsoon">Monsoon</option>
    </select>

     <script>
      $( "#stream" ).change(function() {
           var selectedVal=$("#stream option:selected").val();
            $.ajax({
                 url:"checkonserver.jsp?current_session="+selectedVal,
                 success:function(msg){
                 alert(msg);
                   }
                });
              });
    </script>
    </body>
```

here is my ajax code (checkonserver.jsp)

```
    <body id="body_id" >
    <% if(request.getParameter("current_session").toString().equals("Winter")){%>
        It's COLD
     <% 
     }
       else{
      %>
      It's HOT
    <%}%>
    </body>
```

i got msg from ajax to jquery as fallow ( .jsp page) // it you select monsoon in list

```
<head>
    <body>
        It's HOT         
    <\body>
<\head>
```

my question is how can i parse the `msg` to get data inside the body of above jsp.
for example  : only `its HOT` i want as output on the browser. not entire html file as above

Comment: That seems a very odd value to return. Could you not amend your PHP script to return just the `yes u done` string value? Or better yet, a JSON string with that as the value of a property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

step 1 : give id to field

```
<html>
    <body id="body_id" name="body_name">
        <h1>field comes here</h1>
    <\body>
<\html>
```

step 2 : you can follow any of the code below

```
$.ajax({
    url: "checkonserver.jsp?current_session=" + selectedVal,
    success: function(msg){
        //alert(msg)
        document.getElementById('body_id').innerHTML = msg; // or
        document.getElementByName('body_name').innerHTML = msg; //or
        JQuery('#body_id').value = msg; //or
        JQuery('#body_id').innerHTML = msg; 
    }
});
```

Comment: yes my alert is working, i have posted the code can please check that again. tell me is that is okey ?

Comment: i would suggest one line by one out of the 4 lines i have written inside the success block and check the developers console if it raises any syntax error

Comment: yes sir, its giving results now, after testing keeping all 4 lines in the code. i thought any one line is enough, but i want to know why it is like that ?

Comment: i dont think you need to keep all 4 lines ,keep 1 line at a time and see which 1 gives you output , but i think all of 4 line should work alone

Comment: in my browser the first line is working fine, but the last line is not working, what might be reason ?

Comment: some times this attribute doesnt works (inner html ) , thats why i asked you to try all 4 one at a time

Comment: sir, instead of displaying the result on the body can i have copy of the result into a string . eg  var = body of the output of the ajax ( i.e msg)

Comment: yes man , the response is a string you can store it in any javascript variable

Comment: sir , but it store all the response. i want only the part present the body of the response, so how can i store that in a variable.. before that i would like to say thanks a lot sir, u have given excellent answer.

Comment: hahaha , hey man nether I m a Sir nor you 're a junior , plz skip that part , let me give you some reputation so that you can come in to proivate chat

Answer (score 2):

Under body tag, all data you can get using Jquery:

```
var updatedData = msg;
jQuery(updatedData).find('body').html();
```

Update jquery_test.jsp page:

Remove:

```
url:"checkonserver.jsp?current_session="+selectedVal,
success:function(msg){
    alert(msg);
}
```

Add:

```
url:"checkonserver.jsp?current_session="+selectedVal,
dataType : 'html',
success:function(msg){
    var updatedData = msg;
    alert(jQuery(updatedData).find('body').html());
}
```

Comment: should i place it in jquery block, i have tried, its not even giving the output.

Comment: I have updated the code according to your jquery_test.jsp page jQuery code.

Comment: i have replaced with your code, still its not giving any alert / output sir,

Comment: What value coming in `alert()`?

Comment: <head>
    <body>
        It's HOT         
    <\body>
<\head>

Comment: msg will contain this  : <head>
    <body>
        It's HOT         
    <\body>
<\head>

Comment: sir, tell me how can do assign only body part of "msg" to another variable.   like var result = body party of " msg "

Comment: Again I have updated code, try it. Added DataType while sending AJAX request.

Answer (score 1):

**1. To get JSON From An Array of objects use this**

```
     $.ajax({
                      type:"GET",
                      dataType:"json",
                      url:"thejson",
                      success: function(data) {
                           $.each(data, function(index,element){
                              alert(element.Device);
                         });
                       },
                      error: function() {
                        alert("Not Found File");
                      }
                    });



    JSON Could be like
    [
        {
            "Device": "xklklklx",
            "Count": 5
        }
    ]
```

**2.    To get JSON from Objects Use this:**

```
     $.ajax({
                  type:"GET",
                  dataType:"json",
                  url:"thejson",
                  //data:
                  success: function(data) {
                    alert(data.Device);
                  },
                  error: function() {
                    alert("Not Found File");
                  }
                });

    JSON Can be like:
     {
            "Device": "Some Device",
            "Count": 5
        }
```